# Facing error : "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python

I wrote this programme used to calculate area of a square pyramid. I am facing an error showing : "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable". This is a part of my code, The error is in the line in which the formula is written.

```
    elif shape3d=="5":
    prs=eval(input("Enter the value of Side of Base : "))
    prh=eval(input("Enter the value of Height : "))
    prv=(prh/3)*(prs**2)
    pra=(2*prs)((((prs**2)/4)+(prh**2))**0.5)+(prs**2)
    print("Volume = ",prv)
    print("Surface Area : ",pra)
```

Comment: use * for multiply, do this  `(2*prs)*((((prs**2)/4)+(prh**2))**0.5)+(prs**2)`

Answer (score 1):

`prs`is an integer. But in line 5, you put `pra=(2*prs)((((prs**2)/4)`...
It's the first open bracket after `2*prs` that makes Python think that you're calling a function. Add a `*` in between as I'm guessing that you're multiplying.

Comment: Oh thank you sooo much. I am kind of a newbie so just trying to learn! I am kinda used to not putting the multiplication sign while doing math. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: No problem. Did it work?

Comment: Ya it did work!